# Is there a cron-like implementation of ScheduledExecutorService in Java?

Tags: java, scheduler

The ScheduledExecutorService in Java is pretty handy for repeating tasks with either fixed intervals or fixed delay. I was wondering if there is an something like the existing ScheduledExecutorService that lets you specify a time of day to schedule the task at, rather than an interval i.e. "I want this task to fire at 10am each day".

I know you can achieve this with Quartz, but I'd rather not use that library if possible (it's a great library but I'd rather not have the dependency for a few reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class. Specifically, scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period). Where you can set a task to start at 10am on a particular day and repeat every 24 hours.

Comment: The big issue with this particular method is that it doesn't take daylight savings changes into account.

Comment: I picked this answer as it most accurately answered my question, but I went with the solution in my own answer.

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` is far superior to the `Timer` class, for many reasons.

Answer (score 13):

ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, can be used whenever external thread management is not a requirement. Internally, it delegates to a *ScheduledExecutorService* instance. *ThreadPoolTaskScheduler*  implements Spring’s *TaskExecutor* interface too, so that a single instance can be used for asynchronous execution as well as scheduled, and potentially recurring, executions.

Where as CronTrigger() takes in cronExpression http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

For more information on this solution refer Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;
import java.util.Date;

public class CronTriggerSpringTest{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String cronExpression = "0/5 * * * * *";
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.initialize();
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello Date:"+new Date());
        }
    }, new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
}
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you used the narrative to provide some description of your solution rather than soliciting reputation. Code without description tends to get your answer deleted.

Comment: @rghome please post your comments on the edited post

Comment: Thanks for looking at this solution

Answer (score 5):

A bit more searching has turned up [CronExecutorService](http://ha-jdbc.github.io/apidocs/net/sf/hajdbc/util/concurrent/cron/CronExecutorService.html) in HA-JDBC. Interestingly, it has a dependency on Quartz for its [CronExpression](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) class, but that's it. That's not too bad.

Update: I've fixed the broken links to point at new versions, but I don't know if that is the only dependency any more

Comment: I thought you said you didn't want to use Quartz? What changed your mind? By the way, link is broken.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I didn't want to pull in the *whole* of Quartz, but this only had a dependency on a single class. I extracted just that class from Quartz and used it. (I've also fixed the broken links).

Answer (score 3):

When you use scheduleAtFixedRate you provide a delay. So the delay can be the difference to 10 am and period is 24 hours.
This could drift a bit, even with a timer so what you can do is schedule a task which adds itself to the ScheduledExecutorService with an appropriate delay each time.

Answer (score 1):

JT Cron

http://jarretttaylor.com/java/jt-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

There is [CronScheduler](https://github.com/TimeAndSpaceIO/CronScheduler) which fixes the clock drift problem with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` when the latter is employed to actually schedule in terms of UTC time, Unix time, or system time, rather than in-process abstraction of time provided by `System.nanoTime`.

CronScheduler also offers [`scheduleAtRoundTimesInDay`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.timeandspace/cron-scheduler/latest/io/timeandspace/cronscheduler/CronScheduler.html#scheduleAtRoundTimesInDay-java.time.Duration-java.time.ZoneId-io.timeandspace.cronscheduler.CronTask-) which handles the time zone staff and daylight saving time changes.

```java
Duration syncPeriod = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
CronScheduler cron = CronScheduler.create(syncPeriod);
ZoneId myTZ = ZoneId.systemDefault();
cron.scheduleAtRoundTimesInDay(Duration.ofHours(2), myTZ, runTimeMillis -> {
    // Do the task
});
```